# Trying to get current year in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I have tried different SQL commands like `Year(Getdate())` or `sysdate`, but none of them work.

What I'm trying to do is create a column that gets and stores the current year every time the form is filled out by the user. But for some reason the SQL code doesn't work on Oracle Apex (5.0).

Comment: Are you sure you only need to store the current year? It is much more common to store the date and time when the form was filled out by the user - why only the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECLARE
  CURRENT_YEAR VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY') INTO CURRENT_YEAR FROM DUAL;
  RETURN CURRENT_YEAR;
END;`

use the sql query and paste the item default in oracle apex page item, it will return the current year. not getting an error. 
[check the below image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCoDr.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! The picture helped.

Comment: Thank your comments

Answer (score 1):

The oracle query to get the current year is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work, but I'm getting an error saying that it was expecting INTO. Just for clarity, I am writing this code in the "Settings" part of the "Items" side-bar. \

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer...

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) INTO yourVariable FROM DUAL;
```